# Javascript в чем ошибка

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста, уже голова болит, не могу понять в чем ошибка.

```
function AddShopCartProduct(product){
         alert(product.childNodes[2].innerHTML);
}

...
<li>
    <div id="delete_item"><img src="image/delete_item.png" title="" alt="" /></div>
    <img class="dt_img" src="1005881239.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <p class="dt_hidden_id">345</p>
    <p class="dt_article">Visual C++ в задачах и примерах</p>
    <p class="dt_autor">Н. Культин</p>
    <p class="dt_price">1750<span> руб.</span></p>
    <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="AddShopCartProduct(this.parentNode)">В корзину</a>
</li>
...
```

Нужно что бы вывело то, что находиться  между <p class="dt_hidden_id">345</p>

но почему то выводит undefined.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы используете свойство **childNodes**, которое возвращает не элементы типа Element, а элементы типа Node, а их в результирующей коллекции в два раза больше, поэтому записью **product.childNodes[2]** вы обращаетесь не к параграфу, а к совершенно другому элементу (к какому  - можете посмотреть при отладке). Для решения этой проблемы вам нужно либо фильтровать узловые элементы (признак того, что Node является  Element'ом таков: **nodeType == 1**), либо, что еще проще, написать так:

```
alert(product.children[2].innerHTML);
```

свойство **children** перебирает именно потомков типа Element. Так или иначе, не пренебрегайте пользоваться отладчиком - с его помощью ломать голову вам бы не пришлось